# does azure Integration account support HIPAA version 5010?

Tags: azure, azure-logic-apps, x12, hipaa

I want to decode HIPAA 5010 837 I by Integration account and logic app x12 decoder.Is it possible?

I can see they have support upto 0505

Answer (score 0):

Logic Apps X12 support processing of HIPPA schemas.

One thing to note is, the Agreement UI may not work well with HIPPA schema support. You can use the “Edit As Json” view to add the schema references to the agreement and the X12 decode or encode should work fine.